# Difference between Template helper and Template event handler in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor

What is the difference between using a Template Helper and a Template Event Handler in Meteor.js?

Comment: helper = _show_, event = _do_

Answer (score 2):

These are two completely different things. You use helpers to provide (dynamic) data to a template, for example to display documents from the database. Event handlers are used to react to events that are mostly triggered by the user (like click or scroll events).